# Stock return distribution and expected payoff

Tags: normal-distribution, finance

I just read a working paper and I am trying to get behind the authors' logic of their calculation of a ten-state payoff-diagram of a specific stock (ten payoff states with equal probability).

In their paper they simulate a year worth of daily stock returns with with `mu = 0.06 and sigma = 0.2`.

To calculate the diagram they first calculate the physical quantiles of the lognormal distribution.

`d1 = qlnorm(0.1, 0.06, 0.2), ...,  d10 = qlnorm(1, 0.06, 0.2)`

Then they assume a risk-free rate of 0% and calculate the risk-neutral probability of the physical quantile

`p1 = plnorm(d1, 0.00, 0.2), ... , p10 = plnorm(d10, 0.00, 0.2)`

Finally the 10-state payoff digram looks like this

`s1 = 1/p1 - 1, s2 = 1/(p2-p1) -1, ... , s10 = 1/(p10-p9) -1`

Could someone explain the logic behind this or link me to an article where it explained?

Comment: You should mention the paper in your question.

Comment: It’s unpublished yet and cannot be linked unfortunately

Comment: Two points about your question yet: First of all, in the second line, you still use 0.06 as your $\mu$ parameter whereas you stated that it's a risk-neutral lognormal with risk-free rate 0%. Second point, if those are lognormal distributions, wouldn't the payoff have distribution with parameter $\mu - \sigma^2/2)$ ? I guess it depends what you define as $\mu$, but you have to make that clear to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Raskolnikov you are right and I adjusted the question. About the second part of your questions I am not entirely sure to be honest how to calculate the payoff.

Comment: I would post this at http://quant.stackexchange.com instead.